# Gerunds or Present Participle

Tags: gerunds, present-tense, present-participles

My dog's favorite pastime is sleeping.

I have been told that the word sleeping in this instance, is a gerund, but I have also been told that any "ing" word that follows "to be", in this case "is", is always considered to be a present participle.

Could anyone clear this up for me?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a noun. But note that with verbs other than "be", the _-ing_ word can be a noun or a verb.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a gerund, in effect a noun meaning the state of being asleep.
 If you interpret it as a present participle, your sentence would be saying that a "pastime is sleeping", which doesn't make sense, since pastimes don't go to sleep.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that really helped get my head around it. Is it fair to say then, that the rule that any ing word that follows to be, is not always a present partciple?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The "rule" that it must be a PP is wrong.